# Regular Expression to find specific pattern/text in logs

Tags: python, regex, jenkins, filter, text-processing

I am writing `Python script` for filtering some `log` file and I want to filter text with regular expressions/some library (`preferred regex` as I want to avoid dependency on virtual environment). Below is the text/sentence that I want to look for:

`Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName(). The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed with further tests`

This type of lines may be present in the console log like 20 times. I want to find each instance of this and get that method name `somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()` for every instance (eventually I will collect all names and send an email to myself...but this is later part)

I have attempted this so far `'\[([^\]]+)\] somename.SomeTest.testSomeName() ([^ ]+)'` to find the pattern. But I am not great at regular expressions and might be doing something extra/incorrect.

***EDITTED:***

Changing/expanding the text/string for which I want a regular expression that will find : `somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()` for me.

`21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:170)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:92)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName(). The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed with further tests
21:18:26 somename.client.test.utilities.Platform.PlatformApiException: Platform API returned HTTP 400("Field :case_id is not a valid test case.")
21:18:26    at somename.client.test.utilities.platform.PlatformApiClient.sendRequest(PlatformApiClient.java:197)
21:18:26    at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try using following RE,

```
\w*.\w*.\w*\(\)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iG5rI7/2)

Comment: Yeah, regular expression definitely helped me in getting closer to my desired output of `somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()`-  so, a +1. However, it finds the complete name of `com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()`. Also I edited my question and expanded my string/text for which I want to write a regex to find above `somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()` string.

Comment: Updated the regex, please let me know